# How can I pass a repository resource in as a parameter to AWS codepipeline template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a yml cloudformation template (A) for an AWS codepipeline build that I want to make a variation of it in an another template (B).

The original (A) has a repository as one of its resources which it created when initially run thru cloudformation. I'd like the variation (B) template to use the same ECR repository generated in the original (A), for the codebuild.

Is there a way I can have (B) template use the ECR resource created in A by passing in the repository resource value as a parameter or something?

For example the resource in A that I want to reuse (not recreate) in B is something like :

```
Repository:
  Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
  Properties:
    RepositoryName: !Sub comp/${ServiceName}
    RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          ...
```

Comment: Can you post the template?  You may get better answers with more details.

Comment: added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure from your question what resources you are referring to. But in general you can export any value from one stack into another, using the `Export` property of the `Output` section

From [Exporting Stack Output Values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html)

> To share information between stacks, export a stack's output values.
>   Other stacks that are in the same AWS account and region can import
>   the exported values. For example, you might have a single networking
>   stack that exports the IDs of a subnet and security group for public
>   web servers. Stacks with a public web server can easily import those
>   networking resources. You don't need to hard code resource IDs in the
>   stack's template or pass IDs as input parameters.

Comment: Can you only export literals? how can you export a resource

Comment: A resource will have certain return values that can be exported, and serve to reference the resource in later stacks - it depends on the resource. For AWS::ECR::Repository, you can export the repository name. Check return values here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html#aws-resource-ecr-repository-returnvalues